# Dynamic button only works one time, but not multiple times

Tags: javascript

First, I do not speak English very well.
I hope to apologize.

This is my problem:

I had a button dynamically created with jquery->append. I need this button to change the value of a label `id="exampleid"` from `value="examplefrom"` to `value="exampleto"`.

I create a lot of these buttons with the same ID (example=id"exampleidbuttom") and add events to them with `jquery.ON`.

The buttons change their value from my label one time, and never more.

I don't understand why and i try a lot.

Here a example: http://jsfiddle.net/cvdta/#&togetherjs=kk4Mrix2xG

The HTML:

```
<a href="#"  id="nuevoBoton">Añadir botón</a>
<div id="contenedor">
<a href="#" class="boton" data-val="1">Pulsa</a>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idname" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre del tipo de usuario que deseas crear" name="name"  data-toggle="popover" value="kkk"    dismisible value="">
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$("#nuevoBoton").on('click',function() {

var boton = '<button href="#" class="boton" data-val="' + parseInt(Math.random()*10)+ '">Pulsa</button>';

$('#contenedor').append(boton);    
    $("#contenedor").on('click','button.boton', function() {
     alert('El valor es: ' + $(this).data('val'));  
    $("#idname").remove("value");     
     $("#idname").attr("value","fdfdf");    

   })
```

Comment: ``.remove()`` is for removing elements, not attributes. [See documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

after the resolution here is the code

```
var lastLabel="#idname";
$("#nuevoBoton").on('click',function() {


    var newLabel = "#label"+parseInt(Math.random()*10)


       $(lastLabel).attr("id",newLabel);   
    console.log(newLabel+"-"+lastLabel);
    lastLabel = newLabel;

})
```